# Refresh local receipt for validation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, receipt

I am implementing in-app purchase in my app, and I am doing in-app validation (locally), and I would like to know how to refresh receipt which is stored in:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]appStoreReceiptURL]
```

My problem is :

If I store receipt after purchase the product, and this product are auto-renewable, my local receipt won't know if apple successfully renewed subscription or not.

If person change device, or use two devices, receipt on one device won't know whit user buy on the other device.

So I searching for solution to refresh local receipt befor my app would validate it.

Marko

Answer (score -1):

You can do a simple validation of the receipt which does not request a password by checking the "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" URL
or "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" while in production.

As far as I understood, this is a quick way to check a receipt validity, without sending the credentials and downloading the whole receipt.

You may do the refresh if it fails.

check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

---

About users having two devices, or getting a new version of the app, which seems to come with an incomplete refresh.

A possible solution is to set a UserDefault containing the bundle version at time of the last refresh.
If bundle version do not match at startup, or the UserDefault is not created yet, then send a RefreshRequest to be sure the receipt contains everything. (and update the UserDefault )

Comment: The question is regarding local receipt validation.  Server validation is different.  I am running into this same problem. Hunting for a solution now.